# Bootstrap dropdown icon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown like below:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropleft
  </button>
```

[image]

how to change this dropdown without using css(only bootstrap classes) so that it would have icon
`fas fa-ellipsis-h` instead of name `Dropleft` and left arrow icon?

thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to use something like &#8943 with ; at the end to get ellipsis or you want to include font awesome to get the icon?

Comment: @HemanthB i think that version with `&#8943` will be enough :) you know how to do this?

Comment: &#8943; is the HTML code for Midline Horizontal Ellipsis, HTML will show it as ⋯

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    &#8943;
  </button>
```

I have the same button with Midline Horizontal Ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the class `dropdown-toggle` from button to remove bootstrap icon and add `fas fa-ellipsis-h` class to have you icon.

Example

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary fas fa-ellipsis-h" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropleft
  </button>
```